# Azure FHIR search for resources with _include expression not supported

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir, hl7-v3, fhir-server-for-azure, smart-on-fhir

I'm using following Azure For API(STU3) to play around. I'm trying to get other resources linked to DiagnosticReport resource with _include param.

https://xxx-xxx-xxxx.azurehealthcareapis.com/DiagnosticReport?_id=1234&_include=DiagnosticReport:encounter&_include=DiagnosticReport:result

But I'm getting following error : {
"resourceType": "OperationOutcome",
"id": "af40478f6fe6de47b8e0fc4f40e698ba",
"issue": [
{
"severity": "error",
"code": "forbidden",
"diagnostics": "**Include expression is not supported**."
}
]
}

Comment: Please provide more information

Comment: Found the root cause  we are using CosmosDb not SQL, anyway thanks @FerdinandoSantacroce

Comment: Update: _include has recently been added to the CosmosDb provider

Answer (score 1):

Actually we just figured out that we are using CosmoDb in Azure FHIR which wont support Queries so the include revInclude search params wont work with CosmosDb instead they will work for SQL dbs.